# Sales Representative

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.5

I have a question is about magento. i am making a webstore and getting 1 difficulty. i have created an attribute called SalesRep. for example if i register from the frontend. i will be in customer section at backend. their at backend admin will be able to select me as a sales rep or customer.
if admin select me as salesRep i will become sales rep. Now i want to shop from frontend on behalf of any customer. i should have facility for search customer name from the frontend. at frontend i should be able to shop using customer details. so i logged in and can select any customer who want to shop. and i will shop for this customer.

I hope i explain in full details if you looking for more information please let me know.

Is there any help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento doesn't provide such functionality. Try this free [plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer.html). With it installed you will be able to find a customer in backend, click a "login as a customer" button on customer view page and directly login as a customer in your frontend. Then you can do whatever you need on behalf of the customer, including shopping. However this plugin won't allow customers to pre-select admins who may login on their behalf, i.e. any admin would be able to login as any cusomer.

P.S.: I am not connected to the plugin developer in any other way than I am a happy user of this plugin :)